# state monad on field of record

Tags: monads, coq

I have two types `Foo` and `Bar`, such that `Bar` has a `Foo` as a field.

```
Inductive Foo := ...
Record Bar := { f : Foo }.
```

And I have a "stateful" operation on `Foo`

```
Definition useFoo : state Foo nat := ...
```

Now, I want to apply this `useFoo` to a `Bar` to get a `useBar : state Bar nat`, but I can't figure out how to compose this state monad. I would imagine there is some sort of standard lens that lets me focus a field, but I can't find any.

1. How do I correctly compose a `useFoo : state Foo nat` with something so I get a `useBar : state Bar nat`
2. Is there an easy way to do it in the normal monad notation?
3. How does one usually write "stateful" functions on sub-objects?

---

Some additional information I forgot to include in the beginning:

> Where does the concept of state monad come from?

I use the [MonadState](https://github.com/coq-community/coq-ext-lib/blob/master/theories/Structures/MonadState.v) from [coq ext lib](https://github.com/coq-community/coq-ext-lib).

```
Class MonadState@{s d c} (T : Type@{s}) (m : Type@{d} -> Type@{c}) : Type :=
{ get : m T
; put : T -> m unit
}.
```

> Where was the function state defined?

It's a record in [the StateMonad file from ext-lib](https://github.com/coq-community/coq-ext-lib/blob/master/theories/Data/Monads/StateMonad.v).

```
Record state (t : Type) : Type := mkState { runState : S -> t * S }.
```

> What piece of literature are you basing on?

I am not really basing it on any literature, I just try to use what coq-ext-lib gives me.

Comment: It feels like the question has too little context.  Where does the concept of *state monad* come from?  Where was the function `state` defined?  What piece of literature are you basing on?

Comment: I updated the question with some context

Comment: Great, I think the pointer to ext-lib is instrumental here.

Comment: It might be worth digging in the Haskell standard library / packages / stack overflow for an answer to this, as your question is not really Coq-specific.  (Coq-specific questions would include "how do I encode this particular construction from Haskell / math in Coq?" and "does this Coq library support this monadic feature that is common in Haskell?"). Morally, all you need to focus the state monad is a getter (`Foo -> Bar`) which is postcomposed after the `get`, and a setter (`Foo -> Bar -> Foo`) which is combined with the getter to adjust the update function.